# ffmpeg concat video size smaller than original videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge multiple videos using ffmpeg but the output of concat is half the size of original videos. Below is the ffmpeg command,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -c copy video.mp4
```

All the videos in input file have been split from a big file and converted using the below command,

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[va]" -map "[va]" -strict experimental _file1.mp4
```

They do not have any audio stream to them, so when I try to concat these videos the output file duration is smaller than the original videos combined.

Below is the metadata for the input files,

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.100
    comment         : vid:v09044eb0000bhte9i09pog20dbdosn0
    genre           : aweme_6659292261320329989
  Duration: 00:00:15.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 797 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 794 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler


Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.100
    comment         : vid:v09044a50000bjqkic7smmqi0mu76m20
    genre           : aweme_6697675734137228038
  Duration: 00:00:14.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 718 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 715 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler


Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.100
    comment         : vid:v09044e50000bj0ajcqvfskris7ip2e0
  Duration: 00:00:15.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 548 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 544 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: Did you try using some other files, the command seems to be correct. Did you check the ffprob output of input and output files?

Comment: yes i have checked the metadata and they seem to be same for all the input files..do i need to explicitly specify the type in the command too (even though all of them are of same type ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All inputs don't have the same timebase. First one has `30k tbn` whereas the others have `15360 tbn`.

Convert timebase using the following command and then concat with the new files:

```
ffmpeg -i file2.mp4 -c copy -video_track_timescale 30k file2-30k.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scale one video to match another without pre-defining the dimensions, see the scale2ref filter.

Two videos are provided for input and output. The 1st input is scaled and the 2nd input is unchanged, but used for reference. For example, to put 2 videos side-by-side and have the 2nd video scale to match the first:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:h=in_h:[v1][v0];[v0][v1]hstack[vo]" -map "[vo]" ./output-video.mp4
```